# Being denied access to application in grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am following this tutorial for a Grails forum application: http://grails.asia/grails-forum-application.

I have done exactly what it has in it, except I am using spring-security-core:2.0.0 plugin in stead of spring-security-core:1.2.7.3 in the tutorial mentioned in the tutorial (link given above).

When I try to login: I get this error:

> **"*Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page*"**

I am not sure what the error exactly is as the console does not give a trace.

I am using GGTS Groovy/Grails Tool Suite Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE on Ubuntu Linux 16.04.

The code I am using is the same code listed in the link above and on github (https://github.com/grailsasia/grails-ex-forum)

What am I doing wrong? The application is denying me access even though I am using a username and password that the application is generating itself.

here is the code for Bootstrap.groovy which I am using to load data (again - straight from the tutorial itself):

```
class BootStrap {
    def random = new Random();
    def words = ("time,person,year,way,day,thing,man,world,life,hand,part,child,eye,woman,place,work,week,case,point," +
                "government,company,number,group,problem,fact,be,have,do,say,get,make,go,know,take,see,come,think,look," +
                "want,give,use,find,tell,ask,work,seem,feel,try,leave,call,good,new,first,last,long,great,little,own," +
                "other,old,right,big,high,different,small,large,next,early,young,important,few,public,bad,same,able,to,of," +
                "in,for,on,with,at,by,from,up,about,into,over,after,beneath,under,above,the,and,a,that,I,it,not,he,as,you," +
                "this,but,his,they,her,she,or,an,will,my,one,all,would,there,their").split(",")

    def init = { servletContext ->
        if (SecUser.count() == 0) {  // no user in db, lets create some
            def defaultRole = new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save()
            // create 100 users
            (1..100).each { userNo ->
                String username = "user${userNo}"
                def user = new SecUser(username:username, password: 'secret', enabled: true).save()
                // all users will have default role
                new SecUserSecRole( secUser:user, secRole: defaultRole).save()
            }
        }

        if ( Section.count() == 0 ) { // create data if no forum data found
            // get all users
            def users = SecUser.list()
            // create 3 sections
            ('A'..'C').each { sectionLetter ->
                def sectionTitle = "Section ${sectionLetter}"
                def section = new Section(title: sectionTitle).save()
                // create 4 topics per section
                (1..4).each { topicNumber ->
                    def topicTitle = "Topic ${sectionLetter}-${topicNumber}"
                    def topicDescription = "Description of ${topicTitle}"
                    def topic = new Topic(section: section, title: topicTitle, description: topicDescription).save()
                    // create 10-20 threads each topic
                    def numberOfThreads = random.nextInt(11)+10
                    (1..numberOfThreads).each { threadNo ->
                        def opener = users[random.nextInt(100)]
                        def subject = "Subject ${sectionLetter}-${topicNumber}-${threadNo} "
                        def thread = new DiscussionThread(topic:topic, subject:subject, opener:opener).save()
                        new Comment(thread:thread, commentBy:opener, body:generateRandomComment()).save()
                        // create 10-35 replies per thread
                        def numberOfReplies = random.nextInt(26)+10
                        numberOfReplies.times {
                            def commentBy = users[random.nextInt(100)]
                            new Comment(thread:thread, commentBy:commentBy, body:generateRandomComment()).save()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String generateRandomComment() {
        def numberOfWords = random.nextInt(50) + 15
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
        numberOfWords.times {
            def randomWord = words[random.nextInt(words.length)]
            sb.append("${randomWord} ")
        }
        return sb.toString()
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

I am doing the best I can to figure out what is going on, but I don't have an error message as to what the issue is and the tutorial doesn't help me figure out why.

**UPDATE!!**

After looking at the replies I received, I went back and looked again at the the tutorials, posted in the links and found that my problems are indeed related to the list of permitted roles and accesses.

Here is the list of permitted accesses/roles/resources I need to play with and understand more:

> ```
> // Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'furqanforum.SecUser'
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'furqanforum.SecUserSecRole'
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'furqanforum.SecRole'
> grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
>   '/':                ['permitAll'],
>   '/forum/**':        ['permitAll'],
>   '/index':           ['permitAll'],
>   '/index.gsp':       ['permitAll'],
>   '/assets/**':       ['permitAll'],
>   '/**/js/**':        ['permitAll'],
>   '/**/css/**':       ['permitAll'],
>   '/**/images/**':    ['permitAll'],
>   '/**/favicon.ico':  ['permitAll'],
>   '/login/**':        ['permitAll'],
>   '/logout/**':       ['permitAll']
> ]
> ```

Thanks all who positively contributed to helping me help myself and gain a new skill!

I am reading more on spring security and tweaking and I learn. But based on the checked answer and the replies and suggestions, this solved my issue,

Comment: See ... this is exactly what I mean. Why was this post down voted? AT LEAST state why it is being down-voted. Arbitrary actions like this do not foster growth, nor does it promote encouragement to come to places like this for help.

Comment: If it helps I have upvoted you perhaps, unsure why there is so much downvote perhaps because the angle of the question is not easy to follow - and the answer relatively simple - the issue here is you are in the deep end with spring security and you maybe need to go read stuff about grails spring security before doing tutorial - you can enable spring security debug logs to work out what it is doing - and to cut back on all that look at the static rules generated and simply add your controllers following controllerName/** permitAll rule to give access - that msg is spring security blocking page

Comment: If you follow the tutorial with the version of spring-security it was written for, does it work as expected?

Comment: I think Burt has corretly identified you are on typically wrong version of spring security - perhaps you need to expand your horizon of how you learn so for example looking up grails 2 spring security tutorial youtube turned up this great step by step - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVORfZKAvrM

Comment: you guys are providing a wealth of information! thanks guys. I really mean this. You have helped me so much. I am new to software developing after spending 20 years testing software. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just change from version 1.x to 2.x without any configuration changes. Read the [What's New](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/2.0.x/guide/newInV2.html) information and more specifically read the changes [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/2.0.x/guide/single.html#requestMappings).

Previously the plugin allowed access unless it required a role that the user didn't have, but now the plugin defaults to denying all access unless it's explicitly allowed. Old tutorials that use the 1.x versions of the plugin wouldn't be aware of that.

Comment: All of you have contributed greatly to helping move closer to the solution. Indeed I needed to read more on how to use the plugin (I still need to read on it).

I will update my question with what I found based on the checked solution.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: you guys really helped me a lot.
I have some more reading to do on it, but so far my application is working.